# I am not getting Access token using https://www.upwork.com/api/auth/v1/oauth/token/access

Tags: upwork-api

There are 3 steps for authentication.

1)

get oauth_token `(https://www.upwork.com/api/auth/v1/oauth/token/request)`

2)

get oauth_verifier (by login using webpage)

3)

get access token `(https://www.upwork.com/api/auth/v1/oauth/token/access)`

to get access token I am passing key, secret, access_token, token_secret and oauth_verifier.

I am Getting "not found" error with 404 status code while obtaining access token.

Error description: Not Found: Resource not found for identifier: 'Key'

Comment: please, add some code block, please

Comment: I am trying with Postman.

Answer (score 1):

Please, [contact Support Team](http://support.upwork.com/) and provide the info needed for further investigation - see [Error Handling](https://developers.upwork.com/?lang=python#getting-started_error-handling) section in the documentation.